# Three js light up rectangular sector

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I want to light up a rectangular sector with three js. 
I am looking for something like a rectangular sportlight. 
The problem with the sportlight is that is round not rectangular. 
I tried to use the RectAreaLight but the light does not shine rectangular. 
Maybe somebody has a completly different solution?
I want to highlight a rectangular sector in my 3d model.
In the picture below I used a box as an example. But in my real Application I have a 3d model not only a box.

[image]

Spotlight example:
https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/threejs-lights-spot-w-helper.html

RectAreaLight Example:
https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/threejs-lights-rectarea.html

Source: https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-lights.html

Comment: Hi ! I didn't work with rectangular light but maybe it could help you : https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/lights/RectAreaLight
Here a demo : https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_lights_rectarealight

Comment: Maybe, someday, spotlight "cookies" or textures will be supported: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/14621

Comment: Just do what you would do in real life: Add a light, then a shape below it with a cut-out hole so it casts a shadow with the shape that you want.